# How we can retrieve the data of the checkboxes in another activity in a text view

Tags: android

This is the activity where I defined the checkboxes and Array list.
I have save the result in the arraylist and want to display the same arraylist in another activity.

```
   public ArrayList<String> Result;

   Result = new ArrayList<>();

   public void statuscheck(){

    bcg.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if(bcg.isChecked()){
            Result.add("BCG(Bacillus Calmette and Guérin)");
        }
        else {
            Result.remove("BCG(Bacillus Calmette and Guérin)");
        }
    });

    bopv0.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if(bopv0.isChecked()){
            Result.add("b Oral Polio vaccine(bOPV)-0 ");
        }
        else {
            Result.remove("b Oral Polio vaccine(bOPV)-0 ");
        }
    });

    hepatitis0.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if(hepatitis0.isChecked()){

            Result.add("Hepatitis B birth dose ");

        }


        else {

            Result.remove("Hepatitis B birth dose ");

        }

    });
}
```

the activity where I want to show the arraylist in a text view

```
TextView vac_result;
ArrayList<String> vc_Res;

    vac_result = findViewById(R.id.vac_result);
    vac_result.setEnabled(false);



    vc_Res = vaccineone.Result;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : vc_Res)
        stringBuilder.append("\n");

    vac_result.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
    vac_result.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. You can either pass your data as a `Bundle` when you're trying to call `startActivity()` or use a static global variable across your application.

The snippet below will demonstrate how to use a static variable:

```
class Example {

   public static ArrayList<String> Result = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Fill the static arraylist with your data and simply get the data in the other activity.

Answer (score 0):

Save the "Result" ArrayList with SharedPreferences and in the other activity load the data before trying to work with it.